How does ELK behaves when multiple records are present for the same element on a search?
Let's say we have an index where there are records like these:
{ id:...., name:'first', status:'created', eventDate:01/01/2024, .... }
{ id:...., name:'first', status:'checked', eventDate:02/01/2024, .... }
{ id:...., name:'first', status:'closed', eventDate:03/01/2024, ....}

So, we have several records where, among other data, we register the evolution of our elements status, and say that we have a "first" element created, checked and closed within 3 days.
Now... if I query asking for how many different elements I have, using a unique count of name, only one of those three elements are going to get counted, but I don't know which of them is the selected one.
If I query data between 01/01/2024 and 03/01/2024 and I ask for how many elements are in each different status, I will receive a hit for every one of those records, as all of them are present on my index between those dates. But if I want to filter this for unique names, I don't know which of them is going to be counted.
So, my question is, how are suposed to be managed this type of data? It's suposed to every "past" record to being counted in every case where it match query dates, or there is a best practice to allow "newer" records to be accounted for firstly?

Do you have a unique identifier for the events that are connected to each other?

@hkulekci we do have indeed a unique identifier for each event, but the only connection between events is "name" field, there are not direct relation between event identifiers
